# Create an Array from existing array with additional element added

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

I have a method that takes a vararg Array of strings

```
void count(long delta, String... tags);
```

I have a predefined array of tags for the most cases

```
String[] tags = { "foo_tag:Foo",
                  "bar_tag:Bar",
                  "baz_tag:Baz"
                };
```

and only one tag to be added to predefined tags in each call `"project_id:12345"`

So the call of count should look like this:

```
count(delta, "foo_tag:Foo", "bar_tag:Bar", "baz_tag:Baz", "project_id:12345");
```

How can I simply create a new array containing my existing one plus additional element just in place of calling the method?

Something like this hypothetical `Arrays.append` method:

```
count(delta, Arrays.append(tags, "project_id:12345"));
```

This is storing statistics operation, not business logic, so I want this operation to be as fast as possible.
Currently, I have a helper method `appendTag`, but it doesn't look elegant to me

```
private String[] appendTag(String[] tags, String s)
{
    String[] result = new String[tags.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(tags, 0, result, 0, tags.length);
    result[result.length-1] = s;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you are better off loading that array into ArrayList then just do an add(item_to_add). then if you need an array you can call the ToArray() method of ArrayList

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use a list such as an ArrayList?
If anything, I would have suggested the same solution you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, arrays have a fixed size so **it won't be possible to extend an array** by appending new elements to it.

You will need to create a new array with a larger size and copy the first one elements into it, then add new elements to it, but it's not **dynamic** yet.

What I can suggest is to use a **[`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)** maybe an **[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)** you will profit from its built-in methods like **[`.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E))**

Comment: Yes, looks like this is the only way along with hardcoding static tag values

Comment: @DenisKurochkin Yes, it's the cleanest and safest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to expand an array by one element and add something new.  But if you were working with a list instead, you could easily add a new element and then convert it to an array when calling the method:

```
String[] tags = { "foo_tag:Foo",
                  "bar_tag:Bar",
                  "baz_tag:Baz"
                };
List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tags));
tagList.add("project_id:12345");

count(delta, tagList.toArray(new String[0]));
```

If you think you will have a long term need for this, then perhaps consider changing the implementation of `count()` to use a list instead of an array.  You could also overload this method and expose a version which accepts list instead of array.

Comment: I thought about this, but this is too expensive operation for statistics logging

Comment: @DenisKurochkin Then consider refactoring `count()` to operate on a collection rather than an array.

Comment: `count()` isn't mine, it's 3rd party library

Comment: @DenisKurochkin Could you possibly start out with a larger array with some empty slots?  Does the `count()` method ignore `null` entries?

Comment: predefined empty slots in the array is a kind of anti-pattern, I wouldn't use it